# Problem with logging in Django using django.contrib.auth views

Tags: python, django, django-authentication

When I try to login via LoginView, the process seems successful. I'm redirected to LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL.

```
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views

urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('login', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(), name='login'),
]
```

But when I try to access a view which requires login, I am redirected to login page. When I output request.user.id in a view, this is also None.

```
class MyView(viewsets.ViewSet):

@method_decorator(login_required(login_url='/login'))
def list(self, request, server_id):
    ....
```

What am I missing? Thanks by now.

Here's my login form.

```
<form method="POST" action="{% url 'login' %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Username</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Username">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Password</label>
        <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Try this one here :[https://stackoverflow.com/a/74495300/13730225]

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated


class MyView(viewsets.ViewSet):
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]

    def list(self, request, server_id):
    ....
```

ViewSet is djangoREST class, and sometimes there are some differences in usage between default django and djangoREST views/other components.