# My django views/login form are not working properly

Tags: python, django

I am doing a final project for a programming certificate (Python programming). I have stumbled upon a problem when it came to my views. My MySQL database is connected to django, and I have made an account (through MySQL), yet when I try logging in with these account credentials, it sends the error that these credentials are not valid, or that they don't exist. When I add a print function to the code, it prints the user as "None." However, if I add print to username and password - it prints out the inputted credentials. Thank you in advance...

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import Discount, Store
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login as auth_login
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from .forms import DiscountForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

# Create your views here.
def user_login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        print(username)
        password = request.POST.get('password')
        print(password)
        user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
        print(user)
        if user is not None:
            auth_login(request, user)  # Use auth_login instead of login
            return redirect('discountList')
        else:
            return render(request, 'index.html', {'error': 'Invalid credentials'})

    return render(request, 'index.html')
```

Comment: when you say you "made an account through MySQL" you mean you manually created the user on the database? how did you encrypted the password?

Comment: If `authenticate()` returned None, that means the username/password were incorrect.

Comment: I manually created the user, yes. The password is not encrypted.

Comment: @abeCamelCase: django uses hashing, so manually creating one in the database will *not* work.

Comment: When I printed the username and pass they were correct, though.

Comment: Having a `return` snuck inside an `else` when the other branch *must* `return` is kind of misleading in terms of structure. Ditch the `else` and make it clear the first `if` must `return`.

Comment: @abeCamelCase: yes, but Django does not care about a raw password in the database. It just looks if the password in the database is hashed, if so, repeats the hashing with the same salt, and then checks if both are the same.

Answer (score 0):

Django *hashes* passwords, so manually creating one as raw text in the database will *not* work.

But you don't need to create some view to alter the password, you can use the command line for this with the [**`changepassword`** command <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/django-admin/#django-contrib-auth):

```
python3 manage.py changepassword username
```

this then will hash the given password properly and store it in the database.

---

> **Note**: It is better to use a [**`Form`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/forms/)
> than to perform manual validation and cleaning of the data. A `Form` will not
> only simplify *rendering* a form in HTML, but it also makes it more convenient
> to *validate* the input, and *clean* the data to a more convenient type.

Answer (score 0):

There is a class Name "LoginView", It's a class based views to handle the Login process. To use it :

```
from django.contrib.auth.views import LoginView

class MyLoginForm(LoginView):
    template_name="login.html"
    success_url = reverse_lazy("any url you choose")
```

and the login.html would be like this:

```
<html>
<body>
   <h1>
      Login Form
   </h1>
   <form method="POST">
       {{form.as_p}}
       {% csrf_token %}
       <input value="submit" type="submit"/>
   </form>
</body>
</html>
```

that's more simple than function based views. You can read more about it:
[Classy class based views](https://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/4.2/django.contrib.auth.views/LoginView/)

if you still have problem, maybe you need to delete your migrations and do it again. I hope this could help.

after one day I found the bug you'v created :
views.py

```
user = request.POST["username"]
password = request.POST["password"]
```

correct these lines and your code will work fine.

see this one
"https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74495020/how-to-use-a-django-python-login-form"